Mixed case file names and fields not recognized unless enclosed in quotes
I've been learning my way through PostgresSQL(v16) using PGAdmin 4 (v8.8) and I occasionally rely on files and scripts shared by more experienced analysts. This issue, however, has them stumped: they send me a script that defines a table, with field names that are in all capital letters. When I run the script and try to import data into the new table, however, it fails and says that the fields don't exist. The fields names have become all lower case. I need to enclose field names with upper or mixed cases in quote marks for them to be formatted in that way and I need to do so as well when naming the field in SQL scripts.
Another bottleneck that occurs when importing the .csv files is that the other analysts are pulling in files that contain up to eight million records at a time, but I get a memory error and have to chop the files into three-million-record chunks in order to pull them in, one after the other.
I'm thinking that these unique limitations have to do with the overall database configuration, for which I used mostly default values (though I installed the application and data on a secondary SSD). If it is some help, I've copied the "server configuration" settings from PGAdmin below. Any insights into what might be causing these issues would be most appreciated. Thanks!
"server configuration" from About PGAdmin 4:
ALLOW_SAVE_PASSWORD = True
ALLOW_SAVE_TUNNEL_PASSWORD = False
APP_COPYRIGHT = "Copyright (C) 2013 - 2024, The pgAdmin Development Team"
APP_DEFAULT_EMAIL = "pgadmin4@pgadmin.org"
APP_ICON = "pg-icon"
APP_NAME = "pgAdmin 4"
APP_PATH = "pgadmin"
APP_RELEASE = 8
APP_REVISION = 8
APP_SHORT_NAME = "pgadmin4"
APP_SUFFIX = ""
APP_VERSION = "8.8"
APP_VERSION_EXTN = ('.css', '.js', '.html', '.svg', '.png', '.gif', '.ico')
APP_VERSION_INT = 80800
APP_VERSION_PARAM = "ver"
APP_WIN_PATH = "pgAdmin"
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['internal']
AUTO_DISCOVER_SERVERS = True
AZURE_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_DIR = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\azurecredentialcache"
CA_FILE = "E:\PostgreSQL\PGAdmin\pgAdmin 4\web\cacert.pem"
CHECK_EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY = False
CHECK_SESSION_FILES_INTERVAL = 24
CHECK_SUPPORTED_BROWSER = True
COMPRESS_LEVEL = 9
COMPRESS_MIMETYPES = ['text/html', 'text/css', 'text/xml', 'text/javascript', 'application/json', 'application/javascript']
COMPRESS_MIN_SIZE = 500
CONFIG_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MAX_OVERFLOW = 100
CONFIG_DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE = 5
CONFIG_DATABASE_URI = ""
CONSOLE_LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s    %(name)s:   %(message)s"
CONSOLE_LOG_FORMAT_JSON = OrderedDict({'time': 'asctime', 'message': 'message', 'level': 'levelname'})
CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL = 30
CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY = "default-src ws: http: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
COOKIE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN = None
COOKIE_DEFAULT_PATH = "/"
DATA_DIR = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin"
DEBUG = False
DEFAULT_BINARY_PATHS = {'pg': '$DIR/../runtime', 'ppas': ''}
DEFAULT_SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5050
DESKTOP_USER = "pgadmin4@pgadmin.org"
DISABLED_LOCAL_PASSWORD_STORAGE = False
EFFECTIVE_SERVER_PORT = 58873
ENABLE_BINARY_PATH_BROWSING = False
ENABLE_PSQL = True
ENABLE_SERVER_PASS_EXEC_CMD = False
ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION = True
FILE_LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s   %(name)s:   %(message)s"
FILE_LOG_FORMAT_JSON = OrderedDict({'time': 'asctime', 'message': 'message', 'level': 'levelname'})
FILE_LOG_LEVEL = 30
FIXED_BINARY_PATHS = {'pg': '', 'pg-12': '', 'pg-13': '', 'pg-14': '', 'pg-15': '', 'pg-16': '', 'ppas': '', 'ppas-12': '', 'ppas-13': '', 'ppas-14': '', 'ppas-15': '', 'ppas-16': ''}
HELP_PATH = "../../../docs/en_US/html/"
IS_WIN = True
JSON_LOGGER = False
KERBEROS_CCACHE_DIR = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\krbccache"
KEYRING_NAME = "Windows WinVaultKeyring"
KRB_APP_HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1"
KRB_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
KRB_KTNAME = "<KRB5_KEYTAB_FILE>"
LANGUAGES = {'en': 'English', 'zh': 'Chinese (Simplified)', 'cs': 'Czech', 'fr': 'French', 'de': 'German', 'id': 'Indonesian', 'it': 'Italian', 'ja': 'Japanese', 'ko': 'Korean', 'pl': 'Polish', 'pt_BR': 'Portuguese (Brazilian)', 'ru': 'Russian', 'es': 'Spanish'}
LDAP_ANONYMOUS_BIND = False
LDAP_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
LDAP_BASE_DN = "<Base-DN>"
LDAP_BIND_FORMAT = "{LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE}={LDAP_USERNAME},{LDAP_BASE_DN}"
LDAP_BIND_USER = None
LDAP_CA_CERT_FILE = ""
LDAP_CERT_FILE = ""
LDAP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10
LDAP_DN_CASE_SENSITIVE = False
LDAP_IGNORE_MALFORMED_SCHEMA = False
LDAP_KEY_FILE = ""
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN = "<Search-Base-DN>"
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = "(objectclass=*)"
LDAP_SEARCH_SCOPE = "SUBTREE"
LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://<ip-address>:<port>"
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = "<User-id>"
LDAP_USE_STARTTLS = False
LOGIN_ATTEMPT_FIELDS = ['password']
LOGIN_BANNER = ""
LOG_FILE = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.log"
LOG_ROTATION_AGE = 1440
LOG_ROTATION_MAX_LOG_FILES = 90
LOG_ROTATION_SIZE = 10
MAIL_DEBUG = False
MAIL_PORT = 25
MAIL_SERVER = "localhost"
MAIL_USERNAME = ""
MAIL_USE_SSL = False
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MASTER_PASSWORD_HOOK = None
MASTER_PASSWORD_REQUIRED = True
MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 3
MAX_QUERY_HIST_STORED = 20
MAX_SESSION_IDLE_TIME = 60
MFA_EMAIL_SUBJECT = None
MFA_ENABLED = False
MFA_FORCE_REGISTRATION = False
MFA_SUPPORTED_METHODS = ['email', 'authenticator']
MODULE_BLACKLIST = ['test']
NODE_BLACKLIST = []
OAUTH2_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
OAUTH2_CONFIG = [{'OAUTH2_NAME': None, 'OAUTH2_DISPLAY_NAME': '<Oauth2 Display Name>', 'OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID': None, 'OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET': None, 'OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL': None, 'OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL': None, 'OAUTH2_SERVER_METADATA_URL': None, 'OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL': None, 'OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT': None, 'OAUTH2_SCOPE': None, 'OAUTH2_USERNAME_CLAIM': None, 'OAUTH2_ICON': None, 'OAUTH2_BUTTON_COLOR': None, 'OAUTH2_ADDITIONAL_CLAIMS': None, 'OAUTH2_SSL_CERT_VERIFICATION': True, 'OAUTH2_LOGOUT_URL': None}]
ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 1000
OVERRIDE_USER_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = True
PASSWORD_LENGTH_MIN = 6
PG_DEFAULT_DRIVER = "psycopg3"
PROXY_X_FOR_COUNT = 1
PROXY_X_HOST_COUNT = 0
PROXY_X_PORT_COUNT = 1
PROXY_X_PREFIX_COUNT = 0
PROXY_X_PROTO_COUNT = 1
SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER = "no-reply@localhost"
SECURITY_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PASSWORD_CHANGE_NOTICE = "Your password for pgAdmin 4 has been changed"
SECURITY_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PASSWORD_NOTICE = "Your pgAdmin 4 password has been reset"
SECURITY_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PASSWORD_RESET = "Password reset instructions for pgAdmin 4"
SECURITY_EMAIL_VALIDATOR_ARGS = {'check_deliverability': False}
SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT = 31556952
SERVER_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT = 30
SERVER_MODE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "pga4_session"
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = "/"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_DB_PATH = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\sessions"
SESSION_EXPIRATION_TIME = 7
SESSION_SKIP_PATHS = ['/misc/ping']
SETTINGS_SCHEMA_VERSION = 40
SHARED_STORAGE = []
SHOW_GRAVATAR_IMAGE = True
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SQLITE_PATH = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db"
SQLITE_TIMEOUT = 500
STORAGE_DIR = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\storage"
STRICT_TRANSPORT_SECURITY = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
STRICT_TRANSPORT_SECURITY_ENABLED = False
SUPPORT_SSH_TUNNEL = True
TEST_SQLITE_PATH = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\test_pgadmin4.db"
THREADED_MODE = True
UPGRADE_CHECK_ENABLED = True
UPGRADE_CHECK_KEY = "pgadmin4"
UPGRADE_CHECK_URL = "https://www.pgadmin.org/versions.json"
USER_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 0
WEBSERVER_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
WEBSERVER_REMOTE_USER = "REMOTE_USER"
WEB_SERVER = "Python"
WTF_CSRF_HEADERS = ['X-pgA-CSRFToken']
X_CONTENT_TYPE_OPTIONS = "nosniff"
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "SAMEORIGIN"
X_XSS_PROTECTION = "1; mode=block"


Postgres will always lower case all object names (tables, columns, views, etc.) unless they are double quoted. When an object name is double quoted Postgres retains it as is, but the object must then always be doubled quoted. This is not a configuration setting but a design desicion.

Read Identifiers. If they where experienced analysts they would not be using upper case field names or other forms that require quoting, they would stick with all lower case names.

As to the CSV files, that needs more information. Add as text update to question text the following:  1) How are you moving the file data into the database. 2) What is the exact error message you are getting? 3) What  are the hardware specifications for the machine you are using?
